# How do I raycast from Oculus OVR cameras to Mouse position in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mouse, raycasting, oculus

I'm currently integrating a real-time battleships game I wrote with the Oculus Rift.

The raycasting worked fine when I was doing it from the regular camera, however I am now trying to raycast from the LeftEyeAnchor of the OVRCameraRig to the mouse with no success. This is the code's current state.

```
IEnumerator setupPlayer(){
    int i = 0;

    while (i < 3){
        if(Input.GetKeyDown("s")){

            RaycastHit hit;

            Ray ray = oculusCamera.camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

            if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, 2000)) {
                Debug.Log ("Yay");
                Vector3 shipSpawn = new Vector3 (hit.point.x, hit.point.y+0.6f, hit.point.z);
                if(validPlayerPosition(shipSpawn)){//call test function here
                    shipClone = Instantiate (ship, shipSpawn, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

I spammed the 's' key in an attempt to find somewhere it would hit but to no avail.

I then wrote a short script and attached it to the LeftEyeAnchor camera in an attempt to track its movements and that read as follows.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class mousetrack : MonoBehaviour {
    public Camera oculusCamera;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        Ray ray = oculusCamera.camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 100, Color.red);
    }
}
```

Upon running and moving the headset it did nothing but project a line straight outwards along the z axis , although by removing the headset i could see the frustrum changing in the Unity scene yet the line remained stationary. I searched for issues like my own and came across this thread.

https://forums.oculus.com/viewtopic.php?t=2754

I attempted caliberMengsk's  fix but that made no difference. I am left every runtime with multiple slightly varying instances of the error message:

```
Screen position out of view frustum (screen pos -1061.000000, 837.000000) (Camera rect 0 0 1036 502)
UnityEngine.Camera:ScreenPointToRay(Vector3)
mousetrack:Update() (at Assets/mousetrack.cs:13)
```

which points to this line:

```
Ray ray = oculusCamera.camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
```

Well I am at a loss as to what to do now. Any help on where I'm going wrong would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you raycasting from the camera? You can raycast from the gameobject as well. Have you tried using that? 
if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.forward, out hit)){}

Comment: I resorted to using target reticules and  raycasting out from the cameras position using the same method as you described above.